# SSIS Disable Truncation Warning

Tags: ssis, truncation

I am importing from a flat file that all have a length of NVARCHAR(255).  The destination lengths vary but are usually smaller.  If truncation occurs when inserting into the destination I redirect the Row to an error output and continue processing the rest of the data.  I do not want to correct the data so i simply send it to a reject table. What I have not been able to find is if there is a way to remove the warning sign that appears on the Destination Task itself.  I assumed it would have gone away when i redirected any failures...i was wrong.

Comment: It would go away if you insert not bigger length string than it is set in destination table, so one of solution will be what you in 'Data Conversion' cast to smaller size or 'Derived column' create new column with SUBSTRING function

Comment: if warning comes from Source component you can double click it and in the Error Output tab put Ignore failure under Truncation.

Comment: The warning comes from the destination component.  Yes converting the source size would remove the warning however, there is potential for the source to pass a column w/ a length of 255 and have a destination of 100.  In these cases i want them to be redirected through the truncation error.  I could technically check all 230 columns being passed for truncation issues but this seems absurd when i have a redirect on truncation option in the destination.